# flutter type '_CompactIterable<List<Tasks>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Tasks>'

Tags: flutter

I got this issue:

type '_CompactIterable<List>' is not a subtype of type 'List'

when I try access list back from a List:

```
    List<Map<Project, List<Tasks>>> _data = snapshot.data;
```

I dont know how to access the index values in map back"

```
List<Tasks> _ts = _data[index].values;
```

This always throws error like:

```
Another exception was thrown: type 'CastIterable<List<Tasks>, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Tasks>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try _data.values.toList()[index];

Answer (score 3):

You have a list of maps of lists.
And the `.values` getter returns an Iterable not a list.
So if you do `data[index].values` you get an iterable of lists not a list of tasks.
If you want to combine these lists into a single list you can use the expand method:

```dart
data[index].values.expand((l) => l).toList();
```

Dont forget the toList or you’ll have an Iterable still and will still get an exception

Not sure how you got this to compile though

Comment: thank u Sir. I'll try it. My code seems have syntax error but I indeed get this error when I tried some other approach. May I ask why Dart dont' simply returns a List<Task> to me ? For what kind of concern?

Comment: Do you mean why you need the `toList()`?

Comment: Yes. Why it returns iterable rather than directly list.

Comment: Because then you can do for instance a `values.map(..)` without it needing to write to a list between the values and the map