# type '_CompactIterable<Uint8List>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List'

Tags: flutter

I am fetching images from firebase and save them as a Map with the username id and the image in the Uint8List format. Now I want to filter these maps and distribute the images to where they belong. However, I encountered an error, which I am not sure how to resolve.
Everytime I execute the following code, the line in the if-branch throws the following error:

```
"type '_CompactIterable<Uint8List>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List' "
```

Anyone who has an idea how to resolve this?

```
List<Map> imageBytesList = List<Map<String, Uint8List>>();

(...)

Uint8List imageBytesToGiveToTile;

for(var item in imageBytesList){
  if(tempStringCorted == userProfile.uid){
    imageBytesToGiveToTile = item.values;
  }
}
```

PS: I have seen this thread: [flutter type '_CompactIterable<List<Tasks>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Tasks>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66568980/flutter-type-compactiterablelisttasks-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listtask) but it does not work in my case...

Comment: The problem is that `item.values` is a list of `Uint8Lists`. `imageBytesList` is a list of maps, right? Therefore, `var item` is a `Map` which you defined as `Map<String, Uint8List>`. Therefore, `item.values` is all of the `Uint8Lists` within the map `item`, not just one. Therefore, you get an error trying to shove a list of `Uint8List` into `imageBytesToGiveToTile` which can only be 1 `Uint8List`

Comment: You need to extract a `Uint8List` from `item.values` using `item.values[0]` or something like that